# Polytope and vertex points

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, convex-geometry

Suppose we have a closed polytope $P$ in $\Re^{N}$. Is each point of $P$ a linear combination of the vertices of $P$ (that is its extreme points)? In other words: are the vertices of $P$ a base for the points of $P$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: My opinion is that we can write each point of $P$ as linear combinatin of the vertices of $P$, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Even more is true.  Every $x\in P$ is a *convex* combination of the extreme points $x_e \in P$:
\begin{align}
\sum_e \lambda_e x_e &= x\\
\sum_e \lambda_e &= 1\\
\lambda_e &\ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. Please, can you give me a reference that proves the assertion?

Comment: A proof depends on which equivalent definition of polytope you are using.

Comment: Polytope definition: intersection of a finite number of half-spaces.

Comment: That is one of the definitions of polyhedron.  Does your definition of polytope require boundedness?

Comment: If boundedness is not required, then no version of this claim is true - and in particular, $P$ does not need to have any vertices in that case. So it's only the bounded case that is interesting. (However, in the unbounded case, things improve if we also add the extreme *rays* of $P$.)

Comment: I mean the polytope is bounded (in the question I have wrote "closed polytope").